# How can I retrieve JSON from PHP's specific function using AJAX post Method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Ok so this is the problem I'm facing right now

Actually I've successfully accessed JSON inside php, but with one condition, there is no specific function defined, and right now, I need to access the JSON from specific PHP function

So this is my php looks like

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['func']))
{
    if($_GET['func'] == "add")
       addVisitor();
}
elseif(!empty($_POST['func']))
{
    if($_POST['func']=="retrieve"
        getData()
}

function addvisitor()
{
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "@123";
    $dbname = "numberofvisit";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "UPDATE visitor SET count = count +1 WHERE idvisitor = 1 ";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
}

function getData(){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "@123";
    $dbname = "rating";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 


    $sql = "SELECT avg FROM feedback WHERE idoveralRating=1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $pass=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo json_encode($pass["avg"]);

    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

[Here is My Javascript](http://jsbin.com/foqamenaja/edit?html,css,js,output)

Ok, So Im trying to send request to server to run specific function, by send func=retrieve to addVisit.php  and then after run the function,I catch the JSON that the server Echoed, but it seems like it doesn't work like I expected, here is the part that the code that the part doesn't work for me

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", "addVisit.php", true);
req.send("func=retrieve");
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
```

So How to access JSON in specific function of PHP using ajax?

Comment: `if($_POST['func']=="retrieve"` you have syntax error. You should look at console logs, and server logs for errors. Also, your AJAX request is async, you are trying to parse a response that hasn't arrived yet

Comment: fix syntax error in your JS (line38). Correct is:  `if(desc.css('opacity') === 0 && (flag!==now)){`

Comment: @PatrickEvans damn dude u saved my day, was wondering so long for this, and just realize the mistake ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is case-sensitiv with its funciton names.
You try calling addVisitor()

```
...

if($_GET['func'] == "add")
   add**V**isitor();
}

...
```

But the function name you've defined is:

```
function add**v**isitor()
```

This causes Problems

Which also is pretty helpful for debugging javascript is to use the developer toolkit, often default in your browser (e.g. Chrome or Opera has it by default)
You can dump your javascript variable, calls, returns and debug them by extending your with something like this

```
console.log(variable_name_goes_here)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :- 
call this getData function on button click

```
function getData()
{
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "addVisit.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```